# why my Script does not work after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I made an ajax website and i have a plugin js inside one of my page i load in ajax so when i call my page the script does not work... but! when i resize this page the function work! and if i insert Jquery inside this page the script work perfectly.
so why i can get it when i resize but not when i load my page ?

this is my page.html:

```html
<div class="section vs-section" data-speed="0.4">
  <div class="vs-transform back" data-speed="0.5">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="vs-transform" data-speed="0.35"><a href="projet1.html"><h3 id="short-title">You inspire.</h3></a>
  </div>
  <div class="vs-transform back" data-speed="0.5">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="vs-transform back" data-speed="0.4">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="vs-transform" data-speed="0.35"><a href="projet2.html"><h3>Orange.</h3></a>
  </div>
  <div class="vs-transform back" data-speed="0.37">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="vs-transform back" data-speed="0.38">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="vs-transform" data-speed="0.35"><a href="projet3.html"><h3>Andaman.</h3></a>
  </div>
  <div class="vs-transform back" data-speed="0.38">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="vs-transform back" data-speed="0.3">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="vs-transform back" data-speed="0.3">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {


    var section = document.querySelector('.vs-section');
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.vs-transform');

    var smooth = new Smooth({
      direction: 'horizontal',
      section: section,
      ease: 0.1,
      els: divs
    });
    smooth.init();

  });
</script>
```

and this is my main.js:

```js
   
(function () {
 alert('salut');
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] 
                                   || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }
 
    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); }, 
              timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };
 
    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        };
}());

var vs = (function(document) {
 
 if("undefined" != typeof module && "undefined" != typeof module.exports) var vs = module.exports = {}; else var vs = {};
 
 var numListeners, listeners = [], initialized = false;

 var touchStartX, touchStartY;

 // [ These settings can be customized with the options() function below ]
 // Mutiply the touch action by two making the scroll a bit faster than finger movement
 var touchMult = 1;
 // Firefox on Windows needs a boost, since scrolling is very slow
 var firefoxMult = 15;
 // How many pixels to move with each key press
 var keyStep = 120;
 // General multiplier for all mousehweel including FF
 var mouseMult = 1;

 var bodyTouchAction;

 var hasWheelEvent = 'onwheel' in document;
 var hasMouseWheelEvent = 'onmousewheel' in document;
 var hasTouch = 'ontouchstart' in document;
 var hasTouchWin = navigator.msMaxTouchPoints && navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 1;
 var hasPointer = !!window.navigator.msPointerEnabled;
 var hasKeyDown = 'onkeydown' in document;

 var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') > -1;

 var event = {
  y: 0,
  x: 0,
  deltaX: 0,
  deltaY: 0,
  originalEvent: null
 };

 vs.on = function(f) {
  if(!initialized) initListeners(); 
  listeners.push(f);
  numListeners = listeners.length;
 }

 vs.options = function(opt) {
  keyStep = opt.keyStep || 120;
  firefoxMult = opt.firefoxMult || 15;
  touchMult = opt.touchMult || 2;
  mouseMult = opt.mouseMult || 1;
 }

 vs.off = function(f) {
  listeners.splice(f, 1);
  numListeners = listeners.length;
  if(numListeners <= 0) destroyListeners();
 }

 var notify = function(e) {
  event.x += event.deltaX;
  event.y += event.deltaY;
  event.originalEvent = e;

  for(var i = 0; i < numListeners; i++) {
   listeners[i](event);
  }
 }

 var onWheel = function(e) {
  // In Chrome and in Firefox (at least the new one)
  event.deltaX = e.wheelDeltaX || e.deltaX * -1;
  event.deltaY = e.wheelDeltaY || e.deltaY * -1;

  // for our purpose deltamode = 1 means user is on a wheel mouse, not touch pad 
  // real meaning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent#Delta_modes
  if(isFirefox && e.deltaMode == 1) {
   event.deltaX *= firefoxMult;
   event.deltaY *= firefoxMult;
  } 

  event.deltaX *= mouseMult;
  event.deltaY *= mouseMult;

  notify(e);
 }

 var onMouseWheel = function(e) {
  // In Safari, IE and in Chrome if 'wheel' isn't defined
  event.deltaX = (e.wheelDeltaX) ? e.wheelDeltaX : 0;
  event.deltaY = (e.wheelDeltaY) ? e.wheelDeltaY : e.wheelDelta;

  notify(e); 
 }

 var onTouchStart = function(e) {
  var t = (e.targetTouches) ? e.targetTouches[0] : e;
  touchStartX = t.pageX; 
  touchStartY = t.pageY;
 }

 var onTouchMove = function(e) {
  // e.preventDefault(); // < This needs to be managed externally
  var t = (e.targetTouches) ? e.targetTouches[0] : e;

  event.deltaX = (t.pageX - touchStartX) * touchMult;
  event.deltaY = (t.pageY - touchStartY) * touchMult;
  
  touchStartX = t.pageX;
  touchStartY = t.pageY;

  notify(e);
 }

 var onKeyDown = function(e) {
  // 37 left arrow, 38 up arrow, 39 right arrow, 40 down arrow
  event.deltaX = event.deltaY = 0;
  switch(e.keyCode) {
   case 37:
    event.deltaX = -keyStep;
    break;
   case 39:
    event.deltaX = keyStep;
    break;
   case 38:
    event.deltaY = keyStep;
    break;
   case 40:
    event.deltaY = -keyStep;
    break;
  }

  notify(e);
 }

 var initListeners = function() {
  if(hasWheelEvent) document.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
  if(hasMouseWheelEvent) document.addEventListener("mousewheel", onMouseWheel);

  if(hasTouch) {
   document.addEventListener("touchstart", onTouchStart);
   document.addEventListener("touchmove", onTouchMove);
  }
  
  if(hasPointer && hasTouchWin) {
   bodyTouchAction = document.body.style.msTouchAction;
   document.body.style.msTouchAction = "none";
   document.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", onTouchStart, true);
   document.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", onTouchMove, true);
  }

  if(hasKeyDown) document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);

  initialized = true;
 }

 var destroyListeners = function() {
  if(hasWheelEvent) document.removeEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
  if(hasMouseWheelEvent) document.removeEventListener("mousewheel", onMouseWheel);

  if(hasTouch) {
   document.removeEventListener("touchstart", onTouchStart);
   document.removeEventListener("touchmove", onTouchMove);
  }
  
  if(hasPointer && hasTouchWin) {
   document.body.style.msTouchAction = bodyTouchAction;
   document.removeEventListener("MSPointerDown", onTouchStart, true);
   document.removeEventListener("MSPointerMove", onTouchMove, true);
  }

  if(hasKeyDown) document.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);

  initialized = false;
 }

 return vs;
})(document);


var Smooth = function(opt) {

 if (!(this instanceof Smooth))
  return new Smooth(opt)
  
 this.createBound();

 opt = opt || {}

 this.rAF = undefined;
 
 this.pos = { targetX: 0, targetY: 0, currentX: 0, currentY: 0 };
 
 this.direction = opt.direction || 'vertical';
 
 this.section = opt.section || document.querySelector('.vs-section');
 
 this.ease = opt.ease || 0.1;
 
 this.els = (typeof opt.els != 'undefined') ? Array.prototype.slice.call(opt.els, 0) : [this.section];
 
 this.to = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.vs-scrollto'), 0);

 this.bounding = (this.direction == 'vertical')
  ? this.section.getBoundingClientRect().height - window.innerHeight
  : this.section.getBoundingClientRect().left + this.section.getBoundingClientRect().right - window.innerHeight
  
};

Smooth.prototype.constructor = Smooth;

Smooth.prototype.init = function(){

 var self = this;

 vs.on(this.calc);

 this.els.forEach(function(el){
  el.speed = (self.els.length >= 2) ? el.getAttribute('data-speed') : 1;
 });

 this.to.forEach(function(el){
  var data = el.getAttribute('data-scroll');
  
  el.targetPos = (!isNaN(data))
   ? data
   : (self.direction == 'vertical')
    ? document.querySelector('.'+data).getBoundingClientRect().top
    : document.querySelector('.'+data).getBoundingClientRect().left
  
  el.addEventListener('click', self.getTo.bind(self, el));
 });
 
 document.addEventListener('touchmove', this.prevent);
 window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize);
 
 this.run();

};

Smooth.prototype.createBound = function(){
 
 ['calc', 'getTo', 'prevent', 'resize']
 .forEach(function(fn) {
  this[fn] = this[fn].bind(this);
 }, this);
    
};

Smooth.prototype.prevent = function(e){

 e.preventDefault();

};

Smooth.prototype.calc = function(e){
 
 this.pos.targetY += e.deltaY;
 this.pos.targetX += e.deltaX || e.deltaY
 
 this.pos.targetY = Math.max(this.bounding * -1, this.pos.targetY);
 this.pos.targetY = Math.min(0, this.pos.targetY);

 this.pos.targetX = Math.max(this.bounding * -1, this.pos.targetX);
 this.pos.targetX = Math.min(0, this.pos.targetX);

};

Smooth.prototype.run = function(){

 var self = this;
 var t, s, v, b, r;

 this.pos.currentY += (this.pos.targetY - this.pos.currentY) * this.ease;
 this.pos.currentX += (this.pos.targetX - this.pos.currentX) * this.ease;

 this.els.forEach(function(el) {

  t = (self.direction == 'vertical')
   ? 'matrix3d(1,0,0.00,0,0.00,1,0.00,0,0,0,1,0,0,' + (self.pos.currentY * el.speed).toFixed(2) + ',0,1)'
   : 'matrix3d(1,0,0.00,0,0.00,1,0.00,0,0,0,1,0,' + (self.pos.currentX * el.speed).toFixed(2) + ',0,0,1)'
  s = el.style;

  s['webkitTransform'] = t;
  s['msTransform'] = t;
  s.transform = t;
 
 });
 
 this.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(this.run.bind(this));

};

Smooth.prototype.getTo = function(self, el){

 if(this.direction == 'vertical') this.pos.targetY = -el.target.targetPos;
 else this.pos.targetX = -el.target.targetPos;
 
};

Smooth.prototype.scrollTo = function(offset){

 if(this.direction == 'vertical') this.pos.targetY = -offset;
 else this.pos.targetX = -offset;
 
};

Smooth.prototype.resize = function(){

 this.bounding = (this.direction == 'vertical')
  ? this.section.getBoundingClientRect().height - window.innerHeight
  : this.section.getBoundingClientRect().left + this.section.getBoundingClientRect().right - window.innerHeight

};

Smooth.prototype.destroy = function(){

 vs.off(this.calc);
 
 cancelAnimationFrame(this.rAF);
 this.rAF = undefined;
 
 this.to.forEach(function(el){
  el.removeEventListener('click', self.getTo);
 });
  
 document.removeEventListener('touchmove', this.prevent);
 window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize);

};
```

and my ajax:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    $("#menu a").click(function(){ 
       page=$(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: "pages/"+page,
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
                afficher(html);
    history.pushState({key : 'value'}, 'hash', page);
            }, 
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
                afficher("erreur lors du chagement de la page");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
 
     $('#container').on('click', '.vs-transform a', function(){
  var page=$(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: "pages/"+page,
            cache:false,
            success:function(html){
                showed(html);
    history.pushState({key : 'value'}, 'hash', page);
            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
                showed("erreur lors du chagement de la page");
            }
        });
        return false;
 }); 
window.onpopstate = function(event){
  if(event.state === null){
      // alert('yo');
  }
 };
});

  
function afficher(data){
$("#container").delay( 100 ).fadeOut(400,function(){
    $("#container").empty();    
    $("#container").append(data);
    $("#container").fadeIn(500); 
});
}

function showed(data){
$("#container").delay( 100 ).fadeOut(400,function(){
    $("#container").empty();    
    $("#container").append(data);
    $("#container").fadeIn(500); 
});
}
```

and my index.php where i call my ajax:

```html
        <div id="menu">
     <a id="collection" class="link nav" href="index.html">
        <span>collection</span>
     <a id="about" class="link nav" href="about.html">
        <span>About</span></a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="container">
   <?php
   $d="pages/";
   if(isset($_GET['p'])){
    $p=strtolower($_GET['p']);
    if(preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/",$p) && file_exists($d.$p.".html")){
       include $d.$p.".html";
    }
  else{
    include $d."404.html";
  }
  }
  else{
    include $d."index.html";
  }
   ?>
 </div>
    
    <div id="footer">
      <div class="more-button">
         <a href="#" class="share">Follow me</a>
         <div class="social">
             <a href="http://www.google.fr"><img src="img/icon/Facebook.png"></a> 
             <a href="#"><img src="img/icon/instagram.png"></a> 
                <a href="#"><img src="img/icon/tumbler.png"></a> 
            </div>
            </div>
  
   </div>
```

Comment: wjere did you insert jquery? and here.. for (var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
  }
 what u doing?

Comment: i insert my Jquery in my index.php that call my page in ajax inside a div container.

Comment: is this plugin? https://github.com/baptistebriel/smooth-scrolling ?

Comment: yes and i want get it work when my ajax is load

Comment: and.. where is your ajax code? cant find it...

Comment: i add it in my answer

Comment: Your ``main.js`` is executing immediately because it is wrapped inside an IIFE, make sure that you are not accessing something  that can't be accessed before the page is loaded inside your main.js file.